# when i work with remove() in chrome it works but IE not working

Tags: jquery

when run my mvc application it is working on chrome but not working on IE
the error shows below

```
"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove()'"
```

Comment: Code always helps. As well as which version of jQuery and IE.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Since `.remove()` is not working for you, you could look at straight Javascript with [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to get the job done.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

`elem` being the element you wish to delete

Per your comment try:

```js
function removeRows() {
  $('#AssociateProfilesGrid').find('table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
      this.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AssociateProfilesGrid">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><td>This row will not be removed</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>This row will be removed</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button onclick="removeRows()">Remove()</button>
```

Comment: My code like this-> $("#AssociateProfilesGrid").find('table > tbody > tr').each(function (i, j) {
                      j.remove();
                      });

Comment: AssociateProfilesGrid is telrik gride i am using in MVC5 application with c#.net